# How to get current URL at Before Load user event in SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: suitescript2.0

Is there any way to get current URL's parameters at the Before Load user event in SuiteScript 2.0?

I have tried `document.location.href` and `Context.form.location.href` but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `beforeLoad`'s entry point gives you an `http.ServerRequest` via the `context.request` parameter.

```
 function beforeLoad(context) {
    var parms = context.request.parameters;
    if(parms) {
        // do stuff
    }
 }
```